# Select records from third table while comparing between to other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 3 tables: `artists`, `transactions` and `works`, with these fields:

- **`artists`**: `ArtistsID`, `LastName`, `FirstName`
- **`transactions`**: TransactionID,WorkID,CustomerID
- **`work`** - `WorkID`, `ArtistsID`

What I want to do is:
select the last name and first name of each artist whose work has not been sold by the gallery.

What I have done so far is this:

```
SELECT FirstName
    , LastName
FROM listofartists
    , work
    , trans
WHERE listofartists.ArtistID = work.ArtistID
    AND trans.WorkID NOT IN (
        SELECT workID
        FROM work
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is almost correct, and if you want to keep the `not in` construct you can change the query as follows:

You don't need the `trans` table in the from clause and you need to change the where clause a bit as indicated below.

This will give you those artists that exists in the work table but whose works does not exists in the trans table:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM listofartists
JOIN work ON listofartists.ArtistID = work.ArtistID 
WHERE work.WorkID NOT IN (SELECT workID FROM trans)
```

The query will exclude artists that doesn't have any works at all, but if an artist have both sold and unsold works it will be included - it's not clear if you want to exclude artists with both sold and unsold works.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with out the `JOIN` part? We haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @user6219654 The commas in your query *are* joins. The way that you're learning to write queries was effectively deprecated in the 1990s.

Comment: @user6219654 You could do an implicit join (like in your original query): `SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM listofartists, work WHERE listofartists.ArtistID = work.ArtistID AND work.WorkID NOT IN (SELECT workID FROM trans)` but explicit joins using the `join` keyword are preferred since they were introduced in 1992 and it's better to learn the "right" way sooner rather than later :)

Comment: @jpw We'll probably learn it later, but the instruction was to find a solution based on things we know now. Yet I don't seem to understand why putting trans on FROM wouldn't work for me

Comment: @user6219654 When you put `trans` in the from clause without any matching condition in the where clause that specifies how to connect that table to the others you effectively create a cartesian join (a mapping of all rows in trans to all rows in the other set) which is not what you need. You could do it using left joins as indicated in other answers though - those explicit left join could be rewritten as implicit joins too.

Comment: @jpw Okay, I got it now, thanks, the implicit join like u mentioned before worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a  `left join` and check if the relation could be established with `is null`

```
SELECT listofartists.FirstName, listofartists.LastName
FROM listofartists
LEFT JOIN work ON listofartists.ArtistID = work.ArtistID
LEFT JOIN trans ON trans.WorkID = work.workID 
WHERE work.workID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This can done by by using `LEFT JOIN` and checking `NOT NULL` constraint.

SQL query will look something like this,

```
SELECT A.FirstName, A.LastName
FROM artists A
JOIN work W ON A.ArtistID = W.ArtistID
LEFT JOIN transactions T ON T.WorkID = W.workID 
WHERE T.TransactionID IS NULL
```

In above query we are Joining `artists` table with `work` table to get all the works of each artist, then we're using `LEFT JOIN` of `work` table with `transactions` table which will give all the works regardless of it's entry in transactions table.

Last WHERE condition is making sure that `TransactionID` **IS NULL**, which means the work is does not appear in any transaction.